# Resetting the navigation stack on a UITabBarController doesn't work

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to reset the navigation stack on a subclass of `UITabViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController` but it doesn't work.

My navigation stack, which I create programmatically, is like this:

> UINavigationController => ControllerA (a subclass of UIViewController) =>
>   ControllerB (a subclass of UIViewController) => ControllerC (a
>   subclass of UITabBarController).

When users press on the "Back" button or swipe back from ControllerC, the app should go back to ControllerA, not ControllerB.

Usually, when I want to reset the navigation stack, I do this in the Controller's `viewDidLoad()` method:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()

  // usually work, but not in a subclass of UITabBarController as self.navigationController is nil
  if let navigationController = self.navigationController {

    // keep only the root controller (0) and the current controller
    navigationController.viewControllers = [navigationController.viewControllers[0], self]
  }
}
```

but this doesn't work in ControllerC (the subclass of `UITabViewController`) as `self.navigationController` is nil.

If I do this instead (still in ControllerC's `viewDidLoad()` method):

```
/// ControllerC's viewDidLoad
override func viewDidLoad() {

  super.viewDidLoad()

  if let navigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

    // keep only the root controller (0) and the current controller
    navigationController.viewControllers = [navigationController.viewControllers[0], self]
  }
}
```

This works, but then there is no animation between ControllerB and ControllerC when I do:

```
controllerB.navigationController?.pushViewController(ControllerC(), animated: true)
```

I also tried to override ControllerC's `viewWillDisappear()` method:

```
/// ControllerC's viewWillDisappear
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {

  super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

  if self.isMovingFromParent {

    if let navigationController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {

     navigationController.popToRootViewController(animated: true)
  }
}
```

This works, but ControllerB is briefly visible before ControllerA is shown.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is `ControllerC` a subclassed `UITabBarController`? Or is it the *first View Controller* in your `UITabBarController`?

Comment: Yes it's a subclass of UITabBarController. Thanks for the comment, I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ControllerC instead of trying to override `viewWillDisappear()` method you can override `viewDidAppear()` like that:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        if let navC = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? UINavigationController {
            // keep only the root controller (0) and the current controller
            navC.viewControllers = [navC.viewControllers[0], self]
        }
    }
```

And ControllerB won’t be briefly visible before ControllerA when you navigate backwards.